# Angular Spring Download JSON File

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Can I use this method on different ports? Its working on port :8080 and i can download file but on :4200 i see only logs and nothing more.

Method:

```
@GetMapping("/downloadJson")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadJsonFile() {
        List<Wine> wines = wineService.findAllWines();

        String wineJsonString = jsonExporter.export(wines);

        byte[] wineJsonBytes = wineJsonString.getBytes();

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=wines.json")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(wineJsonBytes);
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <a class="nav-link" (click)="downloadFile()">Download<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

Service:

```
public downloadJsonFile(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/wine/downloadJson`)
```

}

Component:

```
public downloadFile() {
    this.wineService.downloadJsonFile().subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Is this an angular frontend app?  If so,  you need to proxy your requests through the node server to your springboot app.

Comment: Yes, angular frontend app. How can i do it or where could i read about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change download method in component.ts:

```
    public downloadFile(): void {
    this.wineService
      .download()
      .subscribe(blob => saveAs(blob, 'wine.json'));
  }
```

Service:

```
    public download(): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/wine/downloadJson`, {
      responseType: 'blob'
    });
  }
```

To use 'saveAs' in component i had to download new package:

> npm install --save file-saver

and import in app.component.ts

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
```